# Redirect doesn't show notice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to when i create an object to redirect the page to index and show a text.

The default that doesnt redirect the page is :

```
format.html { redirect_to @todo_item, notice: 'Todo item was successfully created.'}
```

so i changed it to redirect to index like this :

```
format.html { redirect_to action: :index, notice: 'Todo item was successfully created.' }
```

but now it does not show the text in the notice, can someone tell me why and how can i fix it?

p.s. if you give me a MINUS please explain in comment what i did wrong so i can improve myself

the code that displays notice in index.html.erb is

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
```

Comment: What does your view code look like that displays the "notice"?

Comment: Can you please post the complete action? Did you double check that the view of the `index` method include logic to present the `notice`?

Comment: I have added how i display notice. <p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

Comment: You just need some curly braces. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trouble is if the first argument is a hash entry like `action: :index` then any other hash entries are assumed to be part of the same hash and so part of the first argument, *not* the response_status that should be in the second argument.

You can fix this by explicitly showing that the `notice` is a separate hash...

```
format.html { redirect_to({ action: :index }, { notice: 'Todo item was successfully created.'}) }
```

Comment: Didnt work :/ 
got : app/controllers/todo_items_controller.rb:31: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '}'

Comment: Ah, it may have been interpreted as a block... try some explicit parentheses around the arguments... I've revised my answer.